# How to delete link in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am currently learning Jquery and i stumbled upon this problem in deleting a link. The problem is can somewhat delete href but not the 'a' itself. is there a better way in deleting the whole a href attribute?  Here is my code. Thanks

```js
var j = jQuery.noConflict();

j('.div table tr:first-child + tr td:first-child + td > a').each(function(){
     j(this).removeAttr("href");
    });
```

```html
<div class=”wrapper”>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Manny</td>
    <td>Weather</td> 
    <td>15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Fight</td>
    <td><a href=http://bet.net><img src=”img/vegas.png”></a></td>  
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: "The problem is can somewhat delete href but not the 'a' itself." do you want to remove the whole anchor including the image inside?

Comment: you would also need to fix the markup. attribute value href is not wrapped correctly.

Comment: @Fabrício Matté you are right, i did not thought about that. so if i target the whole anchor the image inside will also be affected. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();

j('table tr > td > a').each(function() {
    j(this).remove();
});
```

or, if you want to save the `a` tags and put them in later or somewhere else, use

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
var aTags = [];
j('table tr > td > a').each(function() {
    aTags.push(j(this).detach());
});
```

Here's a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ug375v1q/)

Answer (score 0):

you have wrong selector to target anchor elements.for removing attribute `href`,use:

```
$('.wrapper a').removeAttr('href');
```

for completeley removing anchor elements:

```
$('.wrapper a').remove();
```

Comment: it did delete the href but the <a></a> still remains. anyway thanks for the help. i think i will just stay with this.

Comment: @shadowbudz: check the update answer. you need to use `.remove()`